# incorrect redmine installation

Tags: apache, redmine

I am trying to install `redmine 3.2.0` like in the following [article](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_on_Debian_8_with_Apache2-Passenger).

The point `2.4 Test Redmine` works fine, i.e. I am able to open redmine using http://MY_IP:3000.

After this, I did:

```
sudo chown -R www-data files log tmp public/plugin_assets  
sudo chmod -R 755 files log tmp public/plugin_assets  
sudo ln -s /opt/redmine/redmine-3.2.2/public/ /var/www/html/redmine
```

Added `Listen 89` into `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`.

Created the following `sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/redmine.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost MY_IP:89>

    ServerAdmin email@example
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

        <Location /redmine>
                RailsEnv production
                RackBaseURI /redmine
                Options -MultiViews
        </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Enabled `redmine.conf`: `sudo a2ensite redmine.conf`.

Added `PassengerUser www-data` into `/etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf`. Now `passenger.conf` contains the following:

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby
  PassengerUser www-data
</IfModule>
```

And restarted apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`.

So `/var/www/html/` contains:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jan 25 09:32 .
drwxr-x--x 7 root root  4096 Jan 22 07:21 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11104 Jan 22 02:57 index.html
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    34 Jan 25 09:32 redmine -> /opt/redmine/redmine-3.2.0/public/
```

Now if I am going to `http://MY_IP:89` then `/var/www/html/index.html` is opened instead of `redmine home page`.

Could you please advise where I did an error?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

If I use the following `redmine.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost MY_IP:89>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/redmine

        <Directory /var/www/html/redmine>
                RailsBaseURI /
                PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on

                AllowOverride None
                RailsEnv production
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Redmine won't start, only shows `index of` (`/var/www/html/redmine/`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I SOLVED THE ISSUE:**

I did `gem install passenger`. And I use the following `redmine.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost MY_IP:89>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/redmine

        <Directory /var/www/html/redmine>
                RailsBaseURI /
                PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on

                AllowOverride None
                RailsEnv production
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

From passenger 5.2.0 which was released in January 2018 "PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on" is  no longer supported

in your /etc/apache2/sites-available/xxx.conf
make the following changes:

```
# Not supported from passenger 5.2.0 on wards
# PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
PassengerAppRoot /opt/redmine/redmine-3.2.0/public/
```

Answer (score 0):

My redmine works on apache with this config.

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/passenger-5.0.21/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
 PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/passenger-5.0.21
 PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/wrappers/ruby
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost redmine.domain:80>
       ServerName redmine.domain
       ServerAlias redmine
       DocumentRoot /opt/redmine/redmine-3.2.0/public/

    <Directory /opt/redmine/redmine-3.2.0/public/>
    # This relaxes Apache security settings.
    AllowOverride all
    # MultiViews must be turned off.
    Options -MultiViews
    allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Comment: it did not help. still only shows `index of ` (`/var/www/html/redmine/`).  but I don't have `wrappers` folder on my machine...